# Regular expression for hyphens mixed words

Tags: java, regex

I can use **`string.split("\\W+")`** to have words containing only characters.

However:

1. I don't want break down words such as ***"re-use"*** into ***"re"*** & ***"use"***.

   And also words like ***"out-of-the-way"*** with multiple hyphens.
2. I want to break ***"and--oh"*** into ***"and"*** & ***"oh"***.

How can I possibly achieve that?

Comment: where is your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
string.split("[^\\w\\-]+|--+")
```

Comment: but it leaves only punctuations in the vectors

Answer (score 1):

You can replace continuous hyphens to a special character firstly, and then do the simple regex split.

Please refer to the code below.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String str = "This is^^some@@words-apple-banana--orange";
        str = str.replaceAll("[-]{2,}", "@");
        System.out.println(str);
        String regex = "[^\\w-]+";
        String arr[] = str.split(regex);
        for(String item:arr){
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
This are^^some@@words-apple-banana@orange
This
are
some
words-apple-banana
orange
```